# Socket.io isn't installed inside docker

Tags: javascript, docker, socket.io

I'm trying do run my docker image, but I'm having the following error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io'
```

Searching for the bug I saw that inside my node_modules (in docker) the dependence socket.io isn't there.

My package.json is:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "helmet": "^6.0.0",
    "http-errors": "^2.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.7.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rascal": "^16.1.2",
    "socket.io": "^4.5.4",
    "swagger": "^0.7.5",
    "swagger-jsdoc": "^6.2.5",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.6.0"
  },
```

and my docker file:

```
FROM node:16-alpine as base
WORKDIR /src
COPY package*.json ./

FROM base as dev
ENV NODE_ENV=development
COPY ./* .
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

also my docker-compose:

```
version: "3.2"
services:

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: 'mongodb'
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      - mynet
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.11-management-alpine
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672

  backend:    
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./
    volumes:
      - .:/src
      - /src/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - rabbitmq
    environment:
      PORT: 4000
      AMQP_URL: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672
      MONGODB: mongodb://mongodb:27017/mydb
      ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET: secret
    ports:
        - 4000:4000
    networks:
      - mynet

networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
```

Please, can anyone help me?

Comment: It looks like you're storing your `node_modules` tree in an anonymous Docker volume.  This isn't really an appropriate choice for your application's library tree, since it's telling Docker that directory contains user data that must not be changed even if the underlying image is updated.  Does deleting the `backend: { volumes: [...] }` block help?

Comment: Doesn't help. The application just don't start and if I delete the volume `- /src/node_modules` I have the error: `node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1239
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));`
But in this case, the `node_modules` is installed and socket.io is correctly installed.